# Django, How to update image

Tags: python, django

I hope the title is enough to understand my problem, as you can see in the image below, i can get the pciture from my database, the problem is when I update the data and I didnt  change the picture displayed, it makes an error, the cause of the error is I didnt  get any data from html

```
<label for="myfile3">
    <img id="output3"  src="{{selectbanner.image.url}}" style="height:225px;width:250px;" class="subimage"/><br>
    <input type="file" accept="myfile" id="myfile3" name="image" value="{{selectbanner.image.url}}" onchange="loadFile3(event)"  >
</label>
<script>
     var loadFile3 = function(event) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(){
     var output3 = document.getElementById('output3');
     output3.src = reader.result;
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
     };
</script>
```

this is my views.py

```
image = request.FILES.get('image')
print(image)

update = Banner.objects.get(id=banner_id)
    update.image = image
    update.title = Title
    update.sub_title = Sub
    update.description = Description

    update.save()

    return redirect('Banners')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would say you should refer to previously asked related questions.
Refer to these:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492493/django-channels-file-image-upload)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487521/django-image-upload-forms)

[And this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60957703/python-django-image-upload-is-not-working)